# Subset rows in df depending on conditions

Tags: python, pandas

Hello I have a df such as :

I wondered how I can subset row where :

```
COL1 contains a string "ok"
COL2 > 4
COL3 < 4
```

here is an exemple

```
COL1    COL2 COL3
AB_ok_7 5    2
AB_ok_4 2    5
AB_uy_2 5    2
AB_ok_2 2    2
U_ok_7  12   3
```

I should display only :

```
COL1    COL2 COL3
AB_ok_7 5    2
U_ok_7  12   3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
In [2288]: df[df['COL1'].str.contains('ok') & df['COL2'].gt(4) & df['COL3'].lt(4)]
Out[2288]: 
      COL1  COL2  COL3
0  AB_ok_7     5     2
4   U_ok_7    12     3
```

Comment: I get AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'str'

Comment: I have put tested code based on your sample dataframe. Runs fine on my machine. Please make sure to use correct column names as per your dataframe.

Comment: I replaced by : df[df.['COL1'].str.contains('ok') & df.COL2.gt(4) & df.COL3.lt(4)] and it did work thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`boolean indexing`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and chaining all the conditions.

```
m = df['COL1'].str.contains('ok')
m1 = df['COL2'].gt(4)
m2 = df['COL3'].lt(4)
df[m & m1 & m2]

      COL1  COL2  COL3
0  AB_ok_7     5     2
4   U_ok_7    12     3
```